# Deactivate collision between certain Rigidbody objects?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, collision, force-fields, rigidbody

I have a model consisting of many seperate objects that are all overlapping with each other and I want to use Force Fields to "destroy" the model. How can I stop collisions between the objects while still letting them interact with the Force Field and a ground plane?

Comment: In the Rigid Body panel, under Collections, put the objects in different layers, put the ground on several layers at the same time (press Shift to enable several layers)

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do this:

1. Use collision collections to control collisions:

[image]

"Collections" here is kind of legacy; they're not like modern (2.8+) collections.  Instead, by assigning a rigid body to one of the 20 collision collection layers in the rigid body settings, you tell Blender that the object should only undergo collisions with objects that exist in at least one shared layer.  Here, the rigid body cube and floor are in layer 1; the monkey, as shown, is in layer 2.  So the cube lands on the floor while the monkey falls through.

2. Use constraints:

[image]

This is a little more complicated, but there are situations where 20 collision layers aren't enough.  In those cases, you can create rigid body constraints between objects to disable collision between the two, via the "disable collisions" setting on the constraint.  Here, I'm using a generic spring, but without any springs or limits, so it's essentially a "free" constraint that doesn't actually constrain anything.  So the monkey (now in collision layer 1) lands, but the cube doesn't collide with the floor, because of the constraint joining the two.